# Dynamic array in struct

Tags: malloc

Hello I want to create a dynamic array in my struct in C. So that when the user put a number in the main the array is uptated and will have the size that he puts. If you don't understand what i whant to do here his an example that I do but there are a lot of problem.
Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct Bingo
{
int arr_bingo[5][5];
int *pointer_to_arr;
int bingo_choosen_ball[number];
};


int main(){
struct Bingo number1;
int number;
printf("Enter a number");
scanf("%d", &number);

number1->bingo_choosen_ball = malloc(number * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: google for "flexible array member"

Answer (score 0):

Just use an int pointer and malloc it to a desired size.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct Bingo
{
int arr_bingo[5][5];
int *pointer_to_arr;
int *bingo_choosen_ball;
};


int main(){
struct Bingo number1;
int number;
printf("Enter a number");
scanf("%d", &number);

number1->bingo_choosen_ball = malloc(number * sizeof(int));
```

Or you can also use the variable length structure. See the below link

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member